# Laravel Passport - CreateFreshApiToken throwing TokenMismatchException

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I've added `"laravel/passport": "^4.0"` package to my fresh install of laravel 5.5 and to consume my own API, i've added `\App\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class` middleware to the `kernal.php`.

Also, I've scaffolded the Auth login and registration using `php artisan make:auth` as well but whenever I try to login or logout it throws a `TokenMismatchException` and shows me `419` response view.

I checked the `csrf token` inside the auth forms and also `xsrf token` inside cookies which is set by `laravel/passport` package and I found that after changing route to route the token changes which is causing token miss match while logout or login.

[image: exception]

Comment: What is your use case for using passport? Are you trying to oauth or are using it for something like user/token management for an API?

Comment: @kyle I need an oauth setup in my laravel project. Right now i need a basic `user/token` management for my API that's why i used this middleware which is provided by laravel.

Comment: Okay so I see that you are sending the X-CSRF-TOKEN but are you also sending X-Requested-With? And are you using the vue generated components? Unfortunately there is a lot that go wrong when initially setting up passport making it hard to debug w/o really knowing about the app.

Comment: @kyle Oh no no. I'm not making any ajax request. It is Fresh install :-) I've setup the passport by following the documentation and then scaffolded auth from artisan for login and logout. the tokens you are seeing inside the picture is me just var_dump -ed it

Comment: What does your development environment look like? Is the correct APP_URL set in your .env file, APP_URL should be the same as SESSION_DOMAIN?  Also if you are using the file diver for sessions I would check to make sure that the storage folder is writable since laravel stores sessions in storage/framework/sessions.  And lastly does it work if you aren't using passport?

Comment: @kyle Everything was working perfectly. I setup a fresh install of laravel and added the auth using `php artisan make:auth`. Login and register working fine at that point but when i added the `laravel/passport` package and added the `CreateFreshApiTokens` middleware inside the web list. Now it is throwing a TokenMissmatchException everytime i login or logout and sometime when i visit login page.

Comment: Hmm I am running out of ideas... I would ensure that `CreateFreshApiToken` is added to *web* in the kernal, that ` Passport::routes();` has been added to the AuthServiceProvider, that `php artisan passport:client` has been run w/o errors, in config/auth.php, the api driver is `passport`, and lastly your User model uses the `HasApiTokens` trait.  If none of those work you could always ask on the laravel forums